# Need to make each bar as series in highcharts

Tags: javascript, xml, highcharts

I need to make each bar as series in highcharts so that if one clicks on the label under the graph say one clicks 0xx, then this column disappears, so the graph is redesigned, and if one clicks on more columns, the same happens.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so label (on xAxis tick) should hide a column above it, right ?

Comment: yes and chart should redesign itself...

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `solutions`:

1) remove/destroy point http://jsfiddle.net/po9kr7h8/5/ / http://jsfiddle.net/po9kr7h8/6/

2) set value as null  http://jsfiddle.net/po9kr7h8/4/ / http://jsfiddle.net/po9kr7h8/7/

In case when you need to reorganise xAxis, you can also call [setCategories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories)  function.

Comment: Is it possible to show and hide the column when lable under is clicked. Don't want remove the label and column completely just appear and disappear on label click.

Comment: But I did it in my demo, column disappear after click on label.

Comment: I want show that through legend with each column as different series.Like there are 4 columns in first drill down and all four columns should appear on the legend so if I click in 1st legend item then first column disappears.Is it possible with legends when we drill down to first level?

Comment: You need to have each column as separated serie.

Comment: but how to do that.. like data[null,1,null]. But in my chart the at first level drill down chart, the legend is connected to main chart by a single point.Then how to replace legend?

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo, attach mockup before click and after, becuase it is not clear for me.

Comment: If you check this example in http://jsfiddle.net/yPVX9/2/

When the chart is drilldown to Brand version details, like for MSIE browser brand, if I click on the MSIE column it is drill down to MSIE versions.
The version are MSIE 6.0, MSIE 7.0, MSIE 8.0 and MSIE 9.0. In this case the legend is MSIE version.
But I want the legend to be MSIE 6.0, MSIE 7.0, MSIE 8.0 and MSIE 9.0 at this level not MSIE versions.
Hope this is clear.

Comment: Unfortunately in is not possible, you need to have all points as separeted series and update parser.